# c - global variables in pthreads

Tags: c, scope, pthreads

Suppose I defined a function in file function.c, and in main.c I create multiple pthreads to execute the function in function.c.

If in function.c, I define a global variable, for example, int foo;

Then, my question is, does every thread has its own instance of this variable "foo" or do they share a single "foo"?

Comment: Global variables are shared across all threads.

Answer (score 3):

They share a single `foo` variable. Global variable always exists only once per process and is usually protected by mutex to avoid concurrent access.

Since C11 you can use thread_local to declare the variable as local per thread:

```
#include <threads.h>
...
thread_local int perThreadInt;
```

Comment: what if a variable is defined as a local static variable inside the function, will each pthread has its own instance of this variable?

Comment: @RaymondZhang : local static variable is pretty much the same as global variable, just with limited visibility. So no, it will be shared by all threads as well.

Answer (score 2):

A global  varariable is a variable whose scope is within the entire *.c file. They can be accessible wherever they use in same file.

Threads are lightweight process but 
      in  multi-threaded process **(or a multi-threaded file)**  all threads work together to provide different-2 functionality for related process. 
So, because they're not **stand-alone** process so they access global variable in a global manner.

Local variables defined in pthreads are locally accessible in the thread in which they are declared.

**Any thread doesn't know about local variable of another thread** .